# A twist on the leaning ladder problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

For the first part, I know will need to form moment equations and resolve horizontally and vertically. But how do I decide which position to take for the dog while I form moment equations?

Comment: You have to pick an arbitrary position for the dog $(x)$ and solve for $\mu$ as a function of $x$. This will presumably be a function that has a minimum of $\frac45$.

Comment: The solution I checked said that we need to assume the position of the dog at $B$ as this gives the greatest value of $N_b$. I don't understand this. Can you explain?

Comment: If you write the equation as a function of position you will find that B is the place where $\mu$ needs to be greatest. You can try to reason to that point but it is a good exercise to just do the math and convince yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it

Comment: Please read [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) about writing good titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking just at the upper part of the diagram - the ramp leaning against the wall and the block - you can write down the horizontal and vertical components of force as a function of the location of the dog:

[image]

With this diagram in mind you can write down equations for $F_{1h}, F_{2h}, F_{1v}, F_{2v}$ as a function of $x$. You know that the net torque must be zero, that the total vertical force must equal zero, and that the total horizontal force must equal zero. Finally, you know that there is a relationship between $F_{iv}$ and $F_{1h}$ given by the coefficient of friction - and the same is true for the forces against the wall.

This gives you a total of five equations with five unknowns from which you can solve for $\mu$. You will find that $\mu$ is a function of $x$, and that it has its largest value when $x=0$ (for $x$ as drawn here - referenced to the wall).

In the spirit of "homework like" answers, I will leave it up to you to work out the details from here.

You asked for a further hint for part two.

For the cube to slide, the force of friction between the cube and the ground would have to be less than the force of friction between cube and ladder. But the only horizontal force is applied through friction. The same coefficient of friction applies at both points. The cube won't slide if the normal force between cube and ground is larger than between ladder and cube. And of course for any positive value of $k$, that will be true because...

Comment: Could someone give me hint on how to start part two?